drying polymers / FDM 3D printer filaments
My understanding is PLA can absorb 1%, and some others (ABS?) can absorb up to 10% moisture. In order to dry a polymer, is additional (more than room temperature) heat needed (like a filament dryer/drying oven but keeping the temperature below glass transition temperature, ~60 for PLA) or is it enough to keep it in a low humidity (<10%) environment (at room temperature) for some hours ?
More Context: The filaments are vacuum packed with desiccants and should be kept in similar conditions. In case they absorbed some moisture, there are simple driers (basically a small oven at ~60C). I can decrease the humidity in a small closed environment, without using a heat source, where filaments can stay. I wonder if this environment would be enough for drying them.

I am particularly asking about 1.75mm (diameter) filaments (not the printed object). I dont know much about the chemical details other than the basics and some information I learned from the papers I have read (1% and 10% numbers are from such papers). The use is FDM 3D printing, it is known that absorbed moisture in the filament causes problems.

More context added to the question.

What is the relative humidity where the open packages are stored? If you're concerned it's too high, then just store the open reels in an air-tight container, with a packaged desiccant inside, such as CaCl2 (sold widely for use in closets). This is not really a chemistry question, but  more in the line of life-hacks or DIY. BTW, just bake the CaCl2 dry to reuse.

RH is ~45%. I am already keeping them as you described, but when they are used they have to stay in open, and some types can quite quickly absorb moisture. My question is actually simple, how a polymer absorbs and loses moisture. I dont know the mechanism beyond a certain point, buy maybe it is more physics related.
